# Add printer (and similar things) as standard user with sudo rights

Tags: 16.04, sudo

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a computer at work, where I am a standard user with sudo rights.
In many situations (installing software through the software center/adding network printers/...) , I am asked to provide the admin-password, which I don't have.
Most things I can just do in the terminal since I have sudo rights, but sometimes (e.g. when adding printers) this seems to be rather complicated.

Since I have sudo rights, I feel like it should be possible to do these things outside the terminal as well. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, sudo right = admin right. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Did you try to give in your login password when being asked for the *administrator-password*? It should be the same you also use for `sudo`.

Comment: It asks for password of [name of the administrator] and not for my password. When I type my password it does not work. In the terminal, when I run something as sudo it asks me for my password, which works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the output of `groups <USERNAME>`, replace `<USERNAME>` with your username.

Comment: I have done so.

Comment: @J.B. That output is unusual. Even if those *are* your groups, it should show a `:` between your actual username and the list of groups you're in. Can you copy all text from the terminal starting from the beginning of the line that has the prompt on which you typed in the command, paste it in your question instead of what you currently have, then select what you pasted and press Ctrl+K (or click the **{}** button)? That should show exactly what you typed. Right now it is not obvious what you ran. (Did you run `groups [username]` *without* replacing `[username]` with your actual username?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission you had posted indicate a highly configured custom Linux. Standard Ubuntu groups are very different.

This is not unusual for a workplace computer but it may lead to unpredictable results in standard procedures. It may for example be that your administrator had blocked any access to external drives or printers.

Nevertheless you can see whether your root (`sudo`) permissions are sufficient to add yourself to the `lpadmin` group to be able to add a printer to the system.

```
sudo usermod -aG lpadmin <USERNAME>
```

Other groups of interest may be `plugdev`, `sambashare`, `cdrom`, `fuse`. For all groups and privileges read the corresponding list in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Privileges).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I am able to do so (see edited question). It did not change anything about the situation though. I am still asked to provide the password of the admin user.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, I am able now to add printers (I tested with software center). I ended up looking in what groups the admin user is and added myself to those. Unfortunately, I am still not able to install software using software center. This is a minor problem, but it is somehow bugging me.